# How to make ajax calls to a wcf service running on a different port in localhost

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I am developing jquery mobile app from which i have to call the wcf services to get json formatted responses which i use in the jsrender templates.I am testing this app in my local machine.While testing locally i am not getting the results from  the service which runs on a different port from my web project.This is evident by using debuggers like firebug.

I even tried "jsonp" method for cross domain calls from ajax which produced the same results.I am making my calls to the service as below:

```
var urlString = "http://localhost:50046/Security/ValidateUser?username="+encodeURIComponent(userId) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password);

 $.ajax({
           url: urlString,
           dataType: "json",
           success: successFn,
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(errorThrown);
           console.log(errorThrown);
           console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
           if (errorFn) {
                errorFn();
            } else {
                alert("Unable ot connect to server, please try again.");
            }
        }
    });
```

And my page is running on a different port number than the port on which service is running.

Can any one help me where am i going wrong.Is it with the urlstring which i formed or should i use the jsonp callback to make cross domain calls.

I have gone through many links advocating the use of jsonp but am not able to use it in my case.

Awaiting the response .I hope i got my point across in the above lines..

Thanks in Advance
Ramoji

Comment: sorry Mark as i am new to stack overflow i am not allowed to post images until i earn 10 points..